# Making terminal Emacs treat APPS (aka MENU) key as super modifier

Tags: key-bindings

I am working with Emacs on Cygwin, which actually has 3 types of Emacsen:

- Win32 Emacs, which is a graphical Emacs compiled to use native Windows GUI (so no X windows is required)
- Terminal Emacs, which displays in the mintty terminal by default
- X Windows Emacs (requires X, and not relevant to this question)

I am trying to bind the APPS key (the one with the little menu on it, usually to the right of the right-hand Windows key, I think it is properly known as the MENU key, https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Menu_key) to the "super" modifier (gotta love those short key sequences). In Win32 Emacs this is pretty easy:

```
(when (equal window-system 'w32)
    (setq w32-pass-apps-to-system nil
          w32-apps-modifier 'super))
```

This makes Emacs treat APPS as super and stops it passing it onto the OS. It then becomes trivial to make bindings such as

```
(define-key global-map (kbd "s-r") 'recentf-open-files)
```

## Problem

How to make terminal mode Emacs also treat APPS as super? Firstly it was necessary to have mintty changed to pass through the APPS key to Emacs; this has been done already by the maintainer (see https://github.com/mintty/mintty/issues/494) and we can now configure mintty to send any escape sequence we want through to Emacs.

As I said in the issue, the initial suggestion of `Key_Menu=29` (which results in `ESC [ 2 9 ~` appearing in the `view-lossage` log), appears to be interpreted by Emacs as the "<print>" key, so that I can succesfully bind using

```
(global-set-key (kbd "<print> r") 'recentf-open-files)
```

The above, while it is a great advance, is not ideal because 2 sets of bindings would be required, one for terminal mode and one for graphical windowed mode.

## Things that I don't know

- How does Emacs translate a sequence of input characters into a logical key?
- Why does terminal Emacs think the ESC 29 sequence is the print key?
- Does terminal Emacs even know about the APPS key?

## Question

- How can I configure W32 Emacs and terminal Emacs so that they both treat APPS/MENU as the `super` modifier, thus enabling a single set of keybindings to be used in both cases?

Comment: Please edit the post so that it asks one clear question.  If you have multiple questions, feel free to make multiple posts.

Comment: Interesting question!  I don't have an answer, but if you're using mintty, this page may have part of your answer: https://code.google.com/p/mintty/wiki/Keycodes .

Comment: I found out why Emacs thinks it is the `print` key. There is a line in list\term\xterm.el.gz which maps that sequence to print: `(define-key map "\e[29~" [print])`

Comment: Please consider accepting your own answer. This question still shows up on the unanswered list. Thx.

Answer (score 6):

I made quite a bit of progress on this. Reading up on key translation I found [this Emacs manual page](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Translation-Keymaps.html#Translation-Keymaps) on Translation keymaps which has an interesting `hyperify` function

```
(defun hyperify (prompt)
  (let ((e (read-event)))
    (vector (if (numberp e)
                (logior (lsh 1 24) e)
              (if (memq 'hyper (event-modifiers e))
                  e
                (add-event-modifier "H-" e))))))

(defun add-event-modifier (string e)
  (let ((symbol (if (symbolp e) e (car e))))
    (setq symbol (intern (concat string
                                 (symbol-name symbol))))
    (if (symbolp e)
        symbol
      (cons symbol (cdr e)))))

(define-key local-function-key-map "\C-ch" 'hyperify)
```

An equivalent `superify` function can be written by replacing the `lsh 1 24` with `lsh 1 23` (see [Emacs page on character modifier bits](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Other-Char-Bits.html)). However, googling hyperify resulted in a hit on the Emacs wiki called "StickyModifiers" which mentions a built in function to achieve this called `event-apply-super-modifier`. I guess the manual is a bit out of date or it was just for pedagogical purposes. In any case, this will make APPS/MENU into a super key in both terminal and W32 Emacs under mintty:

```
(if (equal system-type 'cygwin)
     (if (equal window-system 'w32)
         (setq w32-pass-apps-to-system nil
               w32-apps-modifier 'super)
       (define-key local-function-key-map (kbd "<print>") 'event-apply-super-modifier)))

 (define-key global-map (kbd "s-h") (lambda () (interactive) (message "hello from menu key via s- prefix")))
```

**Problem** It is not perfect however, because holding the APPS key down results in the string `[29~` being repeatedly written into the buffer, so you have to be quick. Contrast this with the way that the Alt key works: you can hold it down for as long as you want.

**Alternative Technique**
Over at ErgoEmacs I found an article talking about leader keys, which unfortunately I cannot post because reputation is no longer high enough having given it all to bounty. ***SIGH***. Anyway, it is called "emacs_menu_app_keys". Using this technique:

```
(if (equal system-type 'cygwin)
     (if (equal window-system 'w32)
         (setq w32-pass-apps-to-system nil
               w32-apps-modifier nil)
       (progn ;; force all alternatives to <apps> so we can write one set of keybindings.
         (define-key key-translation-map (kbd "<print>") (kbd "<apps>"))
         (define-key key-translation-map (kbd "<menu>") (kbd "<apps>")))))

 (define-key global-map (kbd "<apps> h")
    (lambda () (interactive) (message "hello from menu key via <apps> leader key")))
```

This works great, you press and release APPS before pressing H. I think I prefer it to the first technique as it is easier to type and this prefix key will be reserved for mnemonic-style, one-shot function bindings anyway i.e. nothing that I need to press repeatedly like `C-n`.

**Bounty**
If anybody can come up with something better, especially if they can get the first technique to work as perfectly as using the Alt or Ctrl keys I will still award the bounty to them.

Comment: Sadly, I don't have a menu/apps key, and I can't seem to reproduce the problem without it.

Comment: Late comment:  for some other keys I have written "debouncing" code in AutoHotKey outside of emacs. used for a PTT Push(-and-hold) To Talk key with a speech recognition system, so it wasn't emitting modified characters, just turning the microphone on and off,  and had to kill the multiple key down events produced by autorepeat. I am not sure that I recommend  this because it is timing sensitive,  but it solved my immediate problem -  but eventually  I found a completely different non-PTT approach and I'm no longer using PTT.  // Unfortunately, I cannot try it on your AppsKey right now.