# Emacs super key modifier on Caps Lock in Windows native and Cygwin emacs-w32

Tags: key-bindings, window, keyboard-layout, emacs-w32

I use `super` modifier because it is transparent to any keymap (for example there is no need for <kbd>C-c C-j</kbd> or <kbd>C-c C-x o</kbd> in `term` terminal mode, any `s-...` command just works). Under X I use `xmodmap`.

Under Windows 10 it is hard to use <kbd>Win</kbd> key with letters and arrows key because this key binding is native to Windows (only <kbd>Win+F2</kbd> - <kbd>Win+F12</kbd>, <kbd>Win+Ins</kbd>, <kbd>Win+Del</kbd>, <kbd>Win+PgUp</kbd>, <kbd>Win+PgDown</kbd> passed back to Emacs) and:

```
(setq w32-pass-lwindow-to-system nil
      w32-pass-rwindow-to-system nil
      w32-pass-apps-to-system nil
      w32-lwindow-modifier 'super ; Left Windows key
      w32-rwindow-modifier 'super ; Right Windows key
      w32-apps-modifier 'hyper) ; Menu key
```

doesn't help for LWin in Cygwin `emacs-w32`.

I wonder if it's possible to use <kbd>CapsLock</kbd> as `super` modifier in Windows native and Cygwin emacs-w32...

My laptop has only LWin and the only useless key is <kbd>CapsLock</kbd>... There is num-pad but it is far from my hands usual position...

Comment: "How to bind caps lock" has come up a lot in the past: see the following for option [emacs and caps lock](https://www.google.com/search?client=ubuntu&channel=fs&q=emacs+caps+lock&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8).

Answer (score 4):

I feel your pain. Coming up with a decent hyper/super key binding which will work across all my keyboards is an ongoing search, especially given the widely varying laptop keyboard layouts.

I dislike using the Windows key because it is actually useful when I am in Windows, and Windows steals an ever-increasing set of Win- keypresses at a low level which Emacs cannot intercept.

The approach I am taking is to turn CapsLock into Control, then turn the left Control key into Apps (because not all my keyboards have Apps). Then I do the `w32-apps-modifier` thing to turn it into a hyper key as you are doing in your question. This works well for emacs-w32, you get a genuine non-sticky modifier. In the terminal, it functions as a sticky modifier bound to `<print>` See my question at [Making terminal Emacs treat APPS (aka MENU) key as super modifier](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/18245/making-terminal-emacs-treat-apps-aka-menu-key-as-super-modifier?rq=1) for more details.

I achieved the key remapping using a €15 tool called kbedit http://www.kbdedit.com/. You could probably achieve something similar using AutoHotkey but I like kbdedit because it actually installs a new keyboard layout in Windows rather than intercepting messages. Just feels much cleaner.

Answer (score 1):

There is a solution for my problem, that possible *without any external dependencies*!!

According to https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Windows-Keyboard.html native Emacs can:

```
w32-apps-modifier
  Variable: Modifier to use for the "Apps" key.
w32-lwindow-modifier
  Variable: Modifier to use for the left "Windows" key.
w32-rwindow-modifier
  Variable: Modifier to use for the right "Windows" key.
w32-scroll-lock-modifier
  Variable: Modifier to use for the Scroll Lock ON state.
```

In article [Keyboard and mouse class drivers](https://msdn.microsoft.com/windows/hardware/drivers/hid/keyboard-and-mouse-class-drivers) it is mentioned that it is possible to adjust keyboard layout (for all user) playing with **keycodes**.

There is [Keyboard Scan Code Specification for PS/2 compatible keyboards](http://download.microsoft.com/download/1/6/1/161ba512-40e2-4cc9-843a-923143f3456c/scancode.doc).

Firstly I try to use `w32-scroll-lock-modifier`:

```
(setq w32-scroll-lock-modifier 'super)
```

in order to keep other modifiers without changes:

```
Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Keyboard Layout]
; CapsLock => ScrollLock
"Scancode Map"=hex:00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,02,00,00,00,46,00,3a,00,00,00,00,00
```

but <kbd>Scroll Lock</kbd> **keeps state**, so releasing after first pressing keeps `scroll` **on** as if super key is still pressed and not released.

*It can be emacs-w32 v24 Cygwin bug.* So I moved further and succeeded with:

```
(when (eq window-system 'w32)
  (setq w32-apps-modifier 'super))
```

But my hands trained to work with <kbd>LWin</kbd>, and not with <kbd>Caps Lock</kbd>. So I made 2 swaps and with:

```
; CapsLock (3a,00) => LWin (5b,e0); LWin (5b,e0) => Apps (5d,e0)
"Scancode Map"=hex:00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,03,00,00,00,5b,e0,3a,00,5d,e0,5b,e0,00,00,00,00
```

<kbd>LWin</kbd> key is actually <kbd>Apps</kbd> key and <kbd>LWin</kbd> moved to <kbd>Caps Lock</kbd>.

Now my **Windows** keyboard workflow doesn't differ from **X** workflow.

Of course I disabled layout switching to preserve <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> / <kbd>Alt</kbd> / <kbd>Shift</kbd> solely to Emacs with:

```
[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Keyboard Layout\Toggle]
; The value 1 specifies that LEFT ALT+SHIFT switches locales.
; The value 2 specifies CTRL+SHIFT.
; 3 disables the key sequence altogether.
; I decide use AutoHotkey to switch locales.
;
; These customisations have affect at least after logout/login.
"Hotkey"="3"
"Language Hotkey"="3"
"Layout Hotkey"="3"
```

There is a way to switch layout in Windows 10 with <kbd>Win + Space</kbd> (or <kbd>Caps Lock + Space</kbd> after keyboard layout twicks)!